# Get Chainlink ETH/USD Price Feed answer as uint256 instead of int solidity

Tags: ethereum, solidity, chainlink, hardhat

I want to use the latest ETH price in USD to calculate how much USDC I can borrow from AAVE.

I followed all the tutorials:

```
interface AggregatorV3Interface {
  function decimals() external view returns (uint8);

  function description() external view returns (string memory);

  function version() external view returns (uint256);

  // getRoundData and latestRoundData should both raise "No data present"
  // if they do not have data to report, instead of returning unset values
  // which could be misinterpreted as actual reported values.
  function getRoundData(uint80 _roundId)
    external
    view
    returns (
      uint80 roundId,
      int256 answer,
      uint256 startedAt,
      uint256 updatedAt,
      uint80 answeredInRound
    );

  function latestRoundData()
    external
    view
    returns (
      uint80 roundId,
      int256 answer,
      uint256 startedAt,
      uint256 updatedAt,
      uint80 answeredInRound
    );

}
```

Used the contract for ETH/USD price feed:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419

```
AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x5f4eC3Df9cbd43714FE2740f5E3616155c5b8419);
```

Created the function to get the price:

```
 function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int) {
        (
            uint80 roundID, 
            int price,
            uint startedAt,
            uint timeStamp,
            uint80 answeredInRound
        ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return price;
    }
```

And the function I want to call is this one:

```
 AaveLendingPool.borrow(address(USDT),getLatestPrice(), 1, 0, address(this));
```

this is the error I get:

```
TypeError: Type int256 is not implicitly convertible to expected type uint256.
```

I need to convert the int to unit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can typecast the `int` to `uint` using this syntax: `uint256(input)`

Example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

contract MyContract {
    function foo() external {
        borrow(uint256(getLatestPrice()));
    }
    
    function getLatestPrice() internal returns (int256) {
        return 1;
    }
    
    function borrow(uint256 _number) internal {
    }
}
```